# macOS 10.6.5 upgrade assistance

Tags: itunes

I have a macOS 10.6.5 and am trying to upgrade it but don't know how to, what can I do?

Comment: What kind of Mac (model and year) do you have?

Comment: It's a mac osx 10.6.5 snow leopard 2009

Comment: That‘s the OS, I was more wondering about the specific hardware model. everymac.com might help in identifying it.

Comment: @nohillside I'm not convinced that the other question entirely answers this one. 10.6.5 is pre-MAS. The first thing to do is to apply Software updates (under the Apple Menu?) to get the Mac to 10.6.6 (at least) to access the MAS, and then it should be easy to download a suitable later OS. (I'm curious why Jerome suddenly felt the need to start updating after 10 years, though!) ;-)

Comment: @benwiggy The accepted answer on the linked question explains how to upgrade if your current version doesn‘t support MAS yet.

Comment: @nohillside I can't see "update your 10.6 version beyond 10.6.6 to enable the MAS."

Comment: @benwiggy Look in the „For older macs“ section

Comment: Anyway, without the OP coming back, adding details about the hardware they use, and whether the proposed solution works for them, we won‘t get any more clarity on all this anyway.